# Can someone explain « comment en sommes-nous arrivés là »?

Tags: grammaire, en

I've always been taught it's « arriver à quelque chose » so I'm a little confused why in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwKdczIS72U&ab_channel=BLAST%2CLesouffledel%27info) at 23 seconds the presenter says the line « comment en sommes-nous arrivés là » not « comment y sommes-nous arrivés là » or just simply « comment sommes-nous arrivés là » without en or y because I would've thought the là was enough to indicate some sort of position. Could someone explain why it's « en » and what the difference between the three options are (or if my suggested ones are just invalid)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"En" wears many hats but here it seems to be an adverbial pronoun that denotes initial situation or place:

*Comment en* (= from where we were) *sommes-nous arrivés là* (= to this current state)?

The sentence: « *Comment y sommes-nous arrivés là ?* » is incorrect because “y” and “là” are redundant.

« *Comment sommes-nous arrivés là ?* » is correct but you lose the expression  of contrast of the first sentence.

Comment: For the sake of it, would it be correct to say « comment en y sommes-nous arrivés »?

Comment: @Quippy It would rather be *Comment **y en** sommes nous arrivés* but the phrase would be very uncommon, to say the least.

Answer (score 6):

There is a noticeable difference between

> ***Comment en sommes-nous arrivés là ?***

and

> ***Comment sommes-nous arrivés là ?***

In the former sentence, ***là*** refers to a situation that affect us (a state of affairs, a condition) while in the latter, ***là*** might just mean a physical location.